# Why does this error appear ?: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: primefaces, ejb, java-ee-6

OrganizacionCadenaBean:  initialize()

/**
     * Inicializa el bean con el estado deacuerdo a lo que se esta realizando.
     */
    @Secure
    public void initialize() {
        if (!FacesUtil.isAjax()) {
            /* se inicializan los parámetros iniciales */
            loadInitialParameters();

```
    }
}
```

OrganizacionCadenaBean: loadInitialParameters()

```
/**
     * Se encarga de inicializar el estado del bean según los parámetros.
     */
    public void loadInitialParameters() {
        if (create) {
            log.info("Se va a crear una nueva organizacion");
            /* si viene desde la página de listar para crear */
            edit = Boolean.TRUE;
            instance = new OrganizacionCadena();

            //TODO

        } else {
            log.info("Se va a editar una organizacion existente");
            /* se va a ver o cargar la instancia */
            edit = Boolean.FALSE;
            instance = organizacionCadenaService.findByIdPrefetch(id);
//          idMunicipioSeleccionado = instance.getMunicipio().getId();
//          municipioBean.initialize();
        }

    }
```

OrganizacionCadenaBean: save().

```
/**
     * 
     * Método encargado de guardar la instancia dede finca que se esta
     * gestionando.
     * 
     * @return regla de navegacióndraggable="true"
     */
    @Secure
    public String save() {

        String toReturn = null;

            /* usuario para auditoria */
            instance.setNombreUsuario(credentials.getUsername());

            /* Si está ingresando se persiste */
            try {
                if (create) {
                    //here is the error
                    /* se guarda usando el servicio de finca */
                    organizacionCadenaService.persist(instance);

                    /* se realiza la regla de navegación */
                    if (!edit) {
                        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        params.put(GenericList.MESSAGE, GenericList.PERSIST);

                        toReturn = FacesUtil.navigationRule("/institucion/fincas", true, params);
                    }
                    else{
                        Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                        params.put(GenericList.MESSAGE, GenericList.PERSIST);
                        toReturn = FacesUtil.navigationRule(LIST, true, params);
                    }
                } else {
                    /* se actualiza la instancia */
                    organizacionCadenaService.update(instance);

                    messages.agregarMensaje(Severity.INFO,
                            MessageUtil.MENSAJE_COMUN_UPDATE);

                    /* se vuelve a inicializar el bean */
                    loadInitialParameters();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(
                        "ocurrio un error al tratar de guardar la instancia de organizacion",
                        e);
                messages.agregarMensaje(Severity.ERROR,
                        MessageUtil.COMUN_ERROR_OPERACION);
            }


        return toReturn;
    }
```

GenericService: persist(T instance)

```
 /**
         * 
         * Método encargado de persistir una instancia de la entidad <T> en el
         * sistema.
         * 
         * @param instance
         *            a persistir
         */
        public void persist(T instance) {
            log.info("se va a persistir un registro de la entidad tipo:"+" "+getEntityClass().getName());
            entityManager.persist(instance);
        }
```

When trying to persist the entity in primefaces it says that the error is shown below:

[how the error appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmN1S.png)

the error log:

```
    11:30:30,186 ERROR [org.jboss.ejb3.invocation] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-4) JBAS014134: EJB Invocation failed on component OrganizacionCadenaService for method public void com.traceable.commodities.util.GenericService.persist(com.traceable.commodities.util.CommonEntity): javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleExceptionInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:166) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:230) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:304) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:173) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at com.traceable.commodities.organizacion_cadena_nacional.service.OrganizacionCadenaService$$$view20.persist(Unknown Source) [organizacion_cadena_nacional-ejb.jar:]
    at com.traceable.commodities.organizacion_cadena_nacional.bean.OrganizacionCadenaBean.save(OrganizacionCadenaBean.java:94)
    at com.traceable.commodities.organizacion_cadena_nacional.bean.OrganizacionCadenaBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.save(OrganizacionCadenaBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.interceptor.proxy.SimpleInterceptionChain.invokeNextInterceptor(SimpleInterceptionChain.java:114) [jboss-interceptor-core-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorInvocationContext.proceed(InterceptorInvocationContext.java:143) [jboss-interceptor-core-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at com.traceable.commodities.security.interceptor.SecurityInterceptor.manage(SecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorInvocation$InterceptorMethodInvocation.invoke(InterceptorInvocation.java:72) [jboss-interceptor-core-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.interceptor.proxy.SimpleInterceptionChain.invokeNextInterceptor(SimpleInterceptionChain.java:82) [jboss-interceptor-core-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeInterception(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:133) [jboss-interceptor-core-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.invoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:112) [jboss-interceptor-core-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:53) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at com.traceable.commodities.organizacion_cadena_nacional.bean.OrganizacionCadenaBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.save(OrganizacionCadenaBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.java)
    at com.traceable.commodities.organizacion_cadena_nacional.bean.OrganizacionCadenaBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.save(OrganizacionCadenaBean$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter.doFilter(CatchExceptionFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.ServletEventBridgeFilter.doFilter(ServletEventBridgeFilter.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at com.traceable.commodities.util.FilterUtil.doFilter(FilterUtil.java:36)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.traceable.commodities.util.GenericService.persist(GenericService.java:57) [traceable-util-0.1.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_51]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory$ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptorFactory.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.WeavedInterceptor.processInvocation(WeavedInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:36) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:53) [jboss-as-ee-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.1.Final.jar:1.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:228) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.1.0.Final.jar:7.1.0.Final]
    ... 85 more
```

Comment: Sorry, can't understand, the NPE is because your `entityManager` is null?

Comment: not the log that appears in the code is null due to a bad injection of dependencies.
But it is already solved.